# Trignometry functions in c++ wont return the right values

Tags: c++, output, trigonometry

```
cout << sinf(M_PI) << ", " << cosf(M_PI/2);
```

returns `-8.74228e-08, -4.37114e-08`

what is the smartest way to approach this problem?

I already found out that as the fewer decimal places I round PI to, the closer the functions returns the correct result. See here:

```
    float pi = 3.14;
    cout << sinf(pi) << ", " << cosf(pi/2);
```

returns:

```
0.00159255, 0.000796274
```

But is there a way to maximize the accuracy without eliminating the decimal places?

Comment: `-8.74228e-08` is a lot closer to the correct value than `0.00159255`.  Try this: `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << std::sinf(static_cast<float>(M_PI)) << ", " << std::cosf(static_cast<float>(M_PI/2)) << "\n";`

Comment: What makes you think that 0.00159255 and 0.000796274 are closer to zero than -0.0000000874228 and -0.0000000437114 are?

Comment: Why do you use `sinf` instead of `sin` with `double M_PI`?

Answer (score 2):

The number 8.74228e-08 is less than a tenth of a millionth; this is a much smaller number than 0.00159255. Single precision floats only give you about 7 significant digits of precision so this is indistinguishable from zero as far as a 32-bit float is concerned.

Generally the values of floating point numbers may not be exactly what you expect based on the calculation being performed. It is not uncommon for floating point calculations to have a small amount of error when compared to the true result of some math operation. Beyond precision errors, some numbers, even with non-repeating decimal expansions, cannot be represented exactly with floating point numbers, and pi obviously can't be represented exactly in decimal form at all.

If you want to display floating point numbers and not get scientific notation in your output, use `std::setprecision`. When working with floating point numbers, never test them for exact equality against exact values. Test that the absolute value of their difference from exact values is less than a tolerance, usually referred to as epsilon.

Comment: Floating point numbers **always** have exact values. But people tend to think that floating-point calculations are just like calculations with real numbers, and in that sense, the floating point values often aren't exactly what is expected. The problem is in the expectation, not in the calculation. `int x = 1/3; int y = 3 * x;` programmers learn early on that the value of `y` is not 3. Unfortunately, floating-point math is not taught with this level of detail, if it's taught at all.

Comment: yeah i worded that poorly ... let me try to fix it.